# How to extract first found element of array?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I use this Rxjs:

```
this.menuSubject$
      .pipe(map((items) => items.filter((itm) => itm.active)))
      .subscribe((res) => console.log(res));
```

Where `this.menuSubject$` is:

```
  public menuSubject$ = new BehaviorSubject<MenuItem[]>(menuItems);
```

I want to get `MenuItem` element from array `BehaviorSubject<MenuItem[]>` where property active is true.

Code above works for me but it returns array with element inside `[MenuItem]`, but I need to get `MenuItem`. How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array.filter() returns an array with the result. If you only want one item (the first found) - you can use Array.find() instead.

Like this:

```
this.menuSubject$
      .pipe(map((items) => items.find((itm) => itm.active)))
      .subscribe((res) => console.log(res));
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Answer (score 1):

You can use RxJs's [`mergeMap`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/mergeMap) to flatten the array and [`first`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/first) to emit the first item that matches your condition.

```js
this.menuSubject$
  .pipe(
    mergeMap((item) => item),
    first((item) => item.active)
  )
  .subscribe((res) => console.log(res));
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-mergemap-first?file=index.ts)